# Get the highest of two string variables representing dates

Tags: python, integer, max

I have two variables (`a` and `b`) in the DateTime format 'YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS' (e.g. '20180108T124506'), and I would like to know how to decide which one is more recent. So essentially the highest number.

The problem is that I can't convert it to an integer using `int(variable)` because there's a T in the variable.

How can I circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do anything. `YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS` format is already ordered from most to least significant; this means the [native `str` order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) is equivalent to the desired "time" order.

```py
>>> a = "20180108T124506"
>>> b = "20220108T124506"
>>> b > a
True
>>> max(a, b)
'20220108T124506'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
from datetime import datetime 
a = datetime.strptime("20180108T124506","%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
b = datetime.strptime("20220108T124506","%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")

In [11]: b > a
Out[11]: True
```